# Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I want to convert string to int in linq query and getting following error

> Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32

In the DataBase Filed arID is varchar

```
var AllArea = (from arr in dbcontext.Areas
               join city in dbcontext.Cities on Convert.ToInt32(arr.arID) equals city.cityID
               select new
               {
                   arr.arID,
                   arr.AreaName,
                   city.cityID,
                   city.cityName
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to change your schema instead? This smells like a design issue which is best fixed by changing the database to use more appropriate types.

Comment: Try using `int.Parse(arr.arID)`

Comment: So us the Code for your City Entity class.

Comment: I would preffer TryParse.Int32.TryParse('inputString', out number);
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Try city.cityID.ToString()

Comment: it's not possible change the schema of BD

Answer (score -1):

Try using this `- (int)arr.arID` ...

Comment: A suggestion to try something is not an answer because it's still a gamble and it doesn't explain anything. It might be a comment.